# Why does it print funny characters? unicode problem?

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding

The user entered the word

```
éclair
```

into the search box.

```
Showing results 1 - 10 of about 140 for �air.
```

Why does it show the weird question mark?
I'm using Django to display it:

```
Showing results 1 - 10 of about 140 for {{query|safe}}
```

Comment: Unicode is not a problem, it is a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an encoding problem. Most likely your form or the output page is not UTF-8 encoded.

This article is *very* good reading on the issue: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

You need to check the encoding of

- the HTML page where the user input the word
- the HTML page you are using to output the word
- the multi-byte ability of the functions you use to work with the string (though that probably isn't a problem in Python)

If the search is going to apply to a data base, you will need to check the encoding of the database connection, as well as the encoding of your tables and columns.

Comment: That link wins so hard. +1 Internets to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the result when you interpret data that is not encoded in UTF-8 as UTF-8 encoded.

The interpreter expects from the code point of your first character of the word `éclair` a multibyte encoded character with a length of three characters, consumes the next two characters but can’t decode it (probably invalid byte sequence). For this case the *REPLACEMENT CHARACTER* � (U+FFFD) is shown.

So in your case you just need to really encode your data with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You are serving the page with the wrong character encoding (charset). Check that you are using the same encoding throughout all your application (for example UTF-8). This includes:

- HTTP headers from web server (Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8)
- Communication with database (i.e SET NAMES 'utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

It would also be good to check your browser encoding setting.

Answer (score 0):

I second the responses above. Some other things from the top of my head:

If you're using e.g. MySQL database, then it could be good to create your database using:

CREATE DATABASE x CHARACTER SET UTF8

You can also check this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-charset